# Offline HTML5 web app iOS/Android: under which conditions is it possible?

Tags: html, mobile-application, html5-appcache, hybrid-mobile-app, iphone-web-app

I need to develop a catalogue mobile app, that will be used as products' brochure by the sales employees of the company. I need that the whole catalog of products (the list of products, the single product page, the product search) is accessible also when the device is offline.

I'm sure that this could be easly done developing the app as a native app. But I strongly would prefer to develop it in HTML5 as a web app. But I'm not sure that the HTML5 web app supports the offline access.

Searching on Google I found that if the cache is less than 5MB a web app works well as a native app. But in my scenario the catalogue of products is composed by 120 products, eachone with gallery of photos. So it is much more bigger than 5MB.

In your opinion, how can I deal with the offline access requirement? Maybe an hybrid solution, composed by half a web app and half a native app? Feel free to suggest your approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try an existing hybrid mobile app framework, like: [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). You can build the app using html, CSS, and JavaScript.
http://www.sitepoint.com/top-7-hybrid-mobile-app-frameworks/